# How to loop over files of same format in linux shell

Tags: linux, shell, loops, sed

I want to apply a specific action in various `*.dat` files. What I want to do is use `sed` to remove a specific character using

```
sed 's/"//g' file.dat >file.dat
```

I've tried to use the above code in the following way

```
sed 's/"//g' *.dat > *.dat
```

but it doesn't seem to work for all the files in the directory.

Any idea on how to loop over all those file in linux shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can't read from a file and write to the same file in the same pipeline](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cat_file_.7C_sed_s.2Ffoo.2Fbar.2F_.3E_file), so

```
sed … file > file
```

will fail. In fact, it will truncate the file. Many implementations of `sed` contain the nonstandard `-i` flag, which abstracts the work of writing to a temporary file:

```
sed -i … file
```

So you could do:

```
for dat in *.dat; do
    sed -i 's/"//g' "$dat"
done
```

If your `sed` doesn't have the `-i`, you can use `tr` to remove a single character from files very efficiently:

```
for dat in *.dat; do
    tr -d '"' "$dat" > "$dat.tmp"
    mv "$dat.tmp" "$dat"
done
```

If you want to do this recursively (that is, on file nested within directories within your initial target directory), use either bash's *globstar* setting, or `find`:

```
shopt -s globstar
for dat in **/*.dat; do … # the rest is the same as above
```

or

```
find . -name '*.dat' -exec sed -i 's/"//g' {} \;
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use the `find` command and `sed -i` (the `-i` is in-place). So, the complete command would be something like -

```
find . -name "*.dat" -exec sed -i 's/\"//g' {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
find . -type f -name *.dat -exec sed 's/"//g' {} > {} ';'
```

Comment: You can't read from and write to the same file at the same time.

Comment: my mistake - though you can use the sed option "-i" for in-place change, like Elliott Frisch said above